# place to host a simple php socket server

Tags: php, vps, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

i am running a small project that occasionally requires me to run a php socket script through ssh. it uses a few bytes of bandwidth (just some text) which activates my art installation project.

i tried a simple web hosting plan but that didn't support sockets, so know i am using a 32$ vps plan on namecheap.com just to run a simple php script. i don't really need to host anything else on it. i find it kind of excessive for such a simple thing. is there a place i can run my script for a lower cost? any servers that support php sockets and ssh?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.lowendbox.com/ you can find a lot of cheap VPS hosting packages there, often with promotion codes to make the package even cheaper.

You can easily find a VPS for ~ 5$ there, which should be able to run your script but is much cheaper than your current package.

Make sure to buy from a host which has been in business for sometime though, so you don't find your hoster dead in a couple months and to avoid scammers.